# Inhomogeneous recurrence relation: $x(n) = 2x(n-1)+(n\bmod 2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I solve a recurrence relation given as 
$$x(n)=\begin{cases} 2 x(n-1)+1 &n=\text{odd}\\2 x(n-1) & n=\text{even}\end{cases}$$
I know how to solve them individually,$x(n)=a(2^n)$,where $a$=constant (for homogenous part) and $x(n)$=some constant (for non-homogenous part);ie total solution is $$x(n)=a.2^n+b$$
$a$,$b$ constants.
But how to combine them together to find an integrated solution? Please help.
The solution has been given as:$x(n)=(2/3) 2^n-(1/6)(-1)^n-(1/2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inhomogeneous part is **not** a constant.  The recurrence is

$$x_n - 2 x_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2} [1-(-1)^n]$$

Therefore the inhomogeneous solution $x_n^{(I)}$ is of the form $A + B (-1)^n$.  Substitute that into the equation and determine $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @user71067: if this helped you, please accept the solution by clicking on the checkmark below the number of upvotes.

Comment: this was very very useful.